# oAuth client not caching the token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to create a oAuth client in spring boot using below code. I tried logging the getoken method. As per documentation and code also it must cache the token, I checked the source code in it is checking if the token is empty or if the token expired it is trying to call. But for me each call is responding with a new token. Can you please let me know why this is not cached, does it have to do anything with context?

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("app.oauth2.client")
protected ClientCredentialsResourceDetails oAuthDetails() {
    return new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
}

@Bean
protected OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new OAuth2RestTemplate(oAuthDetails());
}
```

From Spring source code

```
/**
 * Acquire or renew an access token for the current context if necessary. This method will be called automatically
 * when a request is executed (and the result is cached), but can also be called as a standalone method to
 * pre-populate the token.
 * 
 * @return an access token
 */
public OAuth2AccessToken getAccessToken() throws UserRedirectRequiredException {

    OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = context.getAccessToken();

    if (accessToken == null || accessToken.isExpired()) {
        try {
            accessToken = acquireAccessToken(context);
        }
        catch (UserRedirectRequiredException e) {
            context.setAccessToken(null); // No point hanging onto it now
            accessToken = null;
            String stateKey = e.getStateKey();
            if (stateKey != null) {
                Object stateToPreserve = e.getStateToPreserve();
                if (stateToPreserve == null) {
                    stateToPreserve = "NONE";
                }
                context.setPreservedState(stateKey, stateToPreserve);
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }
    return accessToken;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The caching mechanism is against the [Oauth2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), as this standard provides security boundaries to protect any man in the middle attack, CSRF, XSS....

So the oauth2 specification consists of the following concepts for authentication:

1. client-credentials
2. authorization code
3. access token and refresh token

Your use case is the access token, refresh token use case( Oauth2 is build around this concept), so for each access token you have an expiration date, and a refresh token(has a longer expiration date) issued by the server to get a new acces_token.

So the caching part would not respect the oauth2 standard, as it could lead to security issues, such as man in the middle attack.

As per your problem the client should be able by itself to:

1. send access tokens to the backend
2. if the access token expires, or is invalid then request a new refresh token